# How to set custom build cause on invoke() in Python JenkinsAPI

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-api

I am trying to set custom causes for Jenkins builds using the [jenkins api](http://pythonhosted.org/jenkinsapi/).

The [jenkins api](http://pythonhosted.org/jenkinsapi/) has an `invoke()` method for invoking new builds that receives the `cause` parameter.

```
# this is a jenkinsapi.Job method
invoke(self, securitytoken=None, block=False,
           build_params=None, cause=None, files=None, delay=5):
```

The `cause` param is dealt with like this:

```
if cause:
        build_params['cause'] = cause
```

I am trying to find out what format to use when defining a custom cause. In order to do this I first extracted the cause of a build to see what it looks like using `jenkinsapi.Build` method [`get_causes()`](http://pythonhosted.org/jenkinsapi/build.html#jenkinsapi.build.Build.get_causes).

This yields a list of dictionaries as expected (only 1 cause), example:

```
[{'shortDescription': 'description of cause',
  'userId': 'userid',
  'userName': 'username'}]
```

With this knowledge, I tried invoking builds while specifying `cause` as a list of dictionaries in the same format, but this didn't work, upon collecting the causes from this new build, only the normal default cause was there.

**So, my question is what do I need to do to create a custom cause?**

Answer (score 1):

I've found two ways to add in the custom cause but only one way which works with the Jenkin's API. I'm still hoping there's an alternative solution.

To get the custom `cause` setting to work I had to enable this setting in each Jenkin's job:

[image]

After enabling that setting, I was able to trigger the Job with a custom cause which would show up in the console.

```
job.invoke(securitytoken="asecuretoken", cause="A custom cause.")
```

The main trouble I have with this route is that it doesn't fill out the amount of information I see from custom plugins. That's the alternative I've found to using the cause in this manner but it requires more work to implement.

I've found a good example which customizes the build messages based on a REST request is the [GitLab Jenkin's Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin).

Comment: The image cannot be viewed anymore...